# python guessing game int calling

Tags: python

im a beginner with this so I just want to know how I could possibly call int(guess) later in the code?

```
from random import randint
from random import seed

for _ in range(1):
    value = randint(0, 10)
    print(value)
guess = input('guess a number 1-10 ')

if int(guess) == int(value):
    print('gj')

if int(guess) >= int(value):
    print('less!')
    guess = input('guess a number 1-10 ')

if int(guess) <= int(value):
    print('more!')
    guess = input('guess a number 1-10 ')
```

Comment: What do you mean, what do you want to do please explain.

Comment: When you run the code you guess a number then if its less than the number generated, it prints 'less' and goes back to the line   guess = input('guess a number 1-10 ') that is at the start

Comment: And what is the problem/question?

Comment: You need a for or while loop. You have one in `for _ in range(1):` but that goes round the loop only once.

Comment: I want to know if there is a way to go back to the first guess = input('guess a number 1-10 ') line

Answer (score 3):

```
from random import randint

value = randint(0, 10)
print(value)

while True:
    guess = int(input('Guess a number 0-9'))

    if guess == value:
        print('Great job!')
        break

    if guess >= value:
        print('less!')

    if guess <= value:
        print('more!')
```

There's a few things to say here:

1. You don't need your original `for _ in range(1):` - that's a loop, but it will only ever go round the loop one time, so you don't need a loop at all.
2. You can do `guess = int(input('Guess a number 0-9'))` and then you dont need to do `int(guess)` everywhere else.
3. Using a `while True` loop will make the program execute everything in that block forever - or until the `break` statement is reached.

Comment: You are still using `int(guess)` everywhere in your answer :D 4. Also I would say you don't need `int(value)` either as it is already an int.